How did Einstein figure out mass (and hence energy) bends spacetime?
I can understand that once I fix the velocity of light at $c$, there is a relative variation in space-time based on special relativity (inertial frame of reference). It's not clear to me how Einstein figured out how mass (and hence energy) bends spacetime in an accelerated frame (a non-inertial frame of reference). Was that a guess made by Einstein?

Yes and no. Einstein had the revelation of the elevator, that a person that is falling feels no acceleration. We are all used to parabolic trajectories for falling objects. If they are not accelerating, then that means that they are trying to move along straightest possible lines on what must be a curved spacetime, the curvature of which is gravitation. That is half a guess; the specific form of the interaction is purely a guess, but otherwise it is quite well motivated.

The elevator thought experiment convinced him that mass and energy bend space, but he was actually quite resistant to Minkowski's notion of spacetime at first. Eventually he realized that bending of space and time together was necessary for gravity and he came around.

See Why can't I do this to get infinite energy?

Ah! I see what you did there. Light doesn't lose any energy in constant space-time while leaving earth (or in Newton's world, light speed should reduce if gravity was a force, which can't be true based on special relativity). You need to have a space-time hill for the light to lose energy (resulting in a change in frequency), which means space-time is curved. This is brilliant. Is my understanding correct? I was looking for a paradox like this, similar to what we had for special relativity. In that case, quantum physics (E=hv) should have helped Einstein reach that conclusion

I found this explanation interesting.
Why can't I do this to get infinite energy?
Light doesn't lose any energy in constant space-time while leaving earth (or in Newton's world, light speed should reduce if gravity were a force, which can't be true based on Maxwell's equations). You need to have a hill in space for the light to lose energy (resulting in a change in frequency), which means space is curved. The newly developed quantum theory (E=hv) should have helped Einstein reach that conclusion.

Here is a modern translation of Einsteins' paper on general relativity.
http://eotvos.dm.unipi.it/documents/EinsteinPapers/Einstein1911English.pdf

The theory of relativity shows that the inertial mass of a body
increases with the energy it contains; if the increase of energy
amounts to $E$, the increase in inertial mass is equal to $E/c^2$ , where $c$
denotes the velocity of light. Now, is there an increase of
gravitational mass corresponding to this increase of inertial mass? If
not, then a body would fall in the same gravitational field with
varying acceleration according to the energy it contained. And then
the highly satisfactory result of the theory of relativity, by which
the law of the conservation of mass leads to the law of conservation
of energy, could not be maintained, because it would compel us to
abandon the law of the conservation of mass in its old form for
inertial mass, but maintain it for gravitational mass.
This must be
regarded as very improbable. On the other hand, the usual theory of
relativity does not provide us with any argument from which to infer
that the weight of a body depends on the energy contained in it. But
we shall show that our hypothesis of the equivalence of the systems $K$ and $K'$ gives us gravitation of energy
as a necessary consequence.

We have to make a distinction between inertial mass and gravitational mass. Intertial mass is the ratio between force and acceleration as in $F=ma$ and gravitational mass is the scale factor (charge?) in gravitational force, as in $F=G\frac{Mm}{r^2}$.
In his previous work on special relativity, Einstein argued that the inertial mass scales with energy content, which you should recognize in the famous $E=mc^2$. Now, he defines two frames. The frame $K$ is an observer at rest in an uniform gravitational field of acceleration $g$ and $K'$ is an observer accelerating with acceleration $g$ with no gravity present, for example a rocket in space. In both frames it holds true that when you drop an object, which means the only force they experience is gravity, the objects will accelerate towards the floor at $g$.
Now the question arises whether gravitational mass should be equal to inertial mass. In the past this has been experimentally proven and this was an accepted fact at the time. If this is not assumed, we have to abandon conservation of inertial mass. Einstein then shows that if the equivalence principle holds, which says that there is no measurable difference between $K$ and $K'\,^\dagger$, this equivalence of inertial and gravitational mass follows as  a direct result. It just pops out of the math! In the paper I linked there is a nice derivation.
If we now assume the equivalence principle holds, this has some big consequences. For example, light has to bend in a gravitational field. Because it also does in the accelerated frame. The only way to fully reconcile this, is to introduce curvature of spacetime. This means that the metric tensor, which is just a 4-dimensional measuring stick, varies over space$^{\dagger}$.
$\dagger$ the equivalence principle is defined for systems that are small enough. This means we can assume the gravitational field is uniform and we can neglect tidal effects. Or put simply, we assume the gravitational acceleration is the same in the bottom of the elevator and the top.
$\dagger\dagger$ The precise definition is more subtle. Whether the metric tensor is constant, changes when you do a change of coordinates. One way to check if your spacetime is curved, is to transport a vector around a loop in spacetime. If the vector is unchanged for all possible loops, you have a flat spacetime. As an example, the surface of the earth is curved. If you move a vector from the equator, to the north pole, to some other point on the equator and finally back to where you started, you will generally have a different vector.

One justification for the curvature of spacetime comes from the Ehrenfest paradox. Although I'm not sure of its historical significance.
The circumference of a rotating disk is less than that of a stationary disk, by length contraction. The radius, however, is unchanged because it's perpendicular to the direction of motion. Then
\begin{equation}
\text{stationary:}\;\;\;\;\frac{\text{circumference}}{\text{diameter}} = \pi\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{rotating:}\;\;\;\;\frac{\text{circumference}}{\text{diameter}} < \pi
\end{equation}
This is a paradox if we think only in terms of Euclidean geometry. In non-Euclidean geometries, this is a common occurrence as illustrated by the 2-sphere:

In the image above $\frac{C_i}{2r_i} < \pi$, and the opposite inequality occurs in hyperbolic (non-Euclidean) geometry.
Therefore, the relativity of rotations (a type of acceleration) requires non-Euclidean geometry. Then gravitational fields, which are indistinguishable from accelerations (by the equivalence principle), also require non-Euclidean geometry.

In that case, there is enough justification to assume curved space time for gravity.

@iVenky Yes. Then mass (or more generally energy and momentum distributions) must induce this curvature. However historically I’m not sure the exact path Einstein took to this conclusion.

This is easily resolvable with special relativity, so can't be the basis for arguing that general relativity is necessary.
